# How to use Kubernetes pod as jump server to connect to Postgres?

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, pgadmin

I have a pod in a K8s cluster that is allowed to connect into a PG cluster (outside K8s is firewalled).

What is the best way to get this working? I can't seem to get a connection established.

I've tried running `kubectl port-forward`, but connection doesn't seem to work correctly. Do I need the pod to run an SSH server then port forward the SSH server?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect using kubectl port-forward, maybe you just need to double check the settings. The command should be like this:

‘kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 5432:5432 -n <namespace>’

Just replace the pod-name to the designated pod you want to use then the namespace where it is running.

Then try to connect to your PostgreSQL:

‘psql -h localhost -U <username> -d <databasename>’

Attached is some documentation on detailed usage of the kubectl port-forward command.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward

Comment: To clarify, the pod doesn't run the server. The pod is just in the DMZ that has access TO the Postgres cluster.